# Compiler says I'm trying to covert a character to a string, but I'm not

Tags: java

First of, let me preface this by saying that I am a newbie when it comes to coding in Java.  I'm taking an Introduction to Programming class and it's thoroughly kicked my butt so far.

I have a weird issue.  I'm using an online textbook by a website called zyBook.com.  When I submit my program, I get 70/100, and two of the automatic tests fail.  I get this error message:

---

zyLabsUnitTest.java:6: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
       event.addAmount('T', 10);
                       ^
zyLabsUnitTest.java:7: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
       event.addAmount('D', 20);
                       ^
zyLabsUnitTest.java:8: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
       event.addAmount('E', 30);

Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

### 3 errors

and I get this error message:

---

zyLabsUnitTest.java:6: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
       event.addAmount('T', 100);
                       ^
zyLabsUnitTest.java:7: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
       event.addAmount('D', 200);
                       ^
zyLabsUnitTest.java:8: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String
       event.addAmount('E', 160);
                       ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

### 3 errors

Okay, maybe it's just the online textbook I'm using, but I can't see where I'm converting a char to a String anywhere in my code...

This is the first class in my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class EventManager {

public static void main (String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
   String fileName;
   File inFile = null;
   Scanner eventFile = null;

   String amountType;
   double amountValue;


   Event event = null;

   System.out.println("Enter filename:");
   fileName = keyboard.next();

   //keyboard.next();

   try {

       inFile = new File(fileName);

       eventFile = new Scanner(inFile);

       event = new Event();

       while(eventFile.hasNext()) {
           amountType = eventFile.next();
           amountValue = eventFile.nextDouble();

           System.out.printf("Line read: %s %4.2f\n", amountType, amountValue);

           event.addAmount(amountType, amountValue);
       }

       System.out.println("Done reading file " + inFile);
       System.out.println();


       event.displayTotals();
       double netsales = event.calcEventProfit();

       if(netsales > 0) {
           System.out.println("Event generated a profit of $ "+ netsales);
       }
       else {
           System.out.print("Event generated a loss of $ ");
           System.out.printf("%.2f\n", netsales);
       }

   }
```

and here is the second class in my code:

```
public class Event {
private double ticketSales;
private double donations;
private double expenses;

public Event() {
    ticketSales = 0;
    donations = 0;
    expenses = 0;
}


public void addAmount(String type, double amount){
    if(type.equals("T")) {
        ticketSales += amount;
    }
    else if(type.equals("D"))
        donations += amount;
    else if(type.equals("E"))
        expenses += amount;      
}


public void displayTotals() {      
    System.out.printf("%-20s%10.2f\n","Total ticket sales: ",ticketSales);
    System.out.printf("%-20s%10.2f\n","Total donations: ",donations);
    System.out.printf("%-20s%10.2f\n","Total expenses: ",expenses);
    System.out.println();
}



public double calcEventProfit() {
    return (ticketSales + donations - expenses);
}  

public double getTicketSales(){
    return ticketSales;
}

public double getDonations(){
    return donations;
}

public double getExpenses(){
    return expenses;
}

}
```

I really don't where I'm trying to convert a char to a string anywhere.  It runs fine on both Eclipse and NetBeans.

Am I just an idiot who shouldn't be trying to code, or is the textbook having an issue?

Comment: Which scanner version are you using ? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next() , for example ?

Comment: The errors indicate there is a problem with your invocation of the addEvent which is apparently receiving chars instead of strings....

Comment: observe that in the error both  `event.addAmount('D', 200)` and `event.addAmount('T', 100)` have single quotes.

try again with double quotes (like the code example) and it should work

Comment: @EduardoMeneses : (+1) - part of the OP's code is obviously missing.....

Comment: @RannLifshitz not necessarily. It worked for me (pointing directly to a local file in this case).

Comment: The code you posted is OK. If these 2 classes are all your codes, the error would not be code issue. It seems more like environment issue, like issue of compiler and running environment of the website, or maybe some older version of your code is cached and used. And please do check whether you have uploaded latest version of code.

Comment: @EduardoMeneses : so there is some other pathology at work...... Any ideas why ?

Comment: The code I posted is exactly the same code that I uploaded.  That's why I'm so confused as to why it's giving me an error...  Maybe I'll have to contact the textbook website and ask them why.  I made sure to have the double quotes around the D, T, etc  

The only code missing is my comments at the top.

Comment: The text file it reading just says:

    T 1100.00
    E 444.44
    D 100.00
    D 250.00
    D 222.00
    E 555.55

since I used "eventFile.next();" it would only get the single character before the first whitespace.  I don't know exactly how Java does things, but could it possibly be trying to automatically convert it to a char when it only reads the single letter?

Comment: All your error messages start with **zyLabsUnitTest.java:6:** ... which you are not showing. Probably because that is not **your** code. It rather looks like **their** unit tests have a bug!

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense.  I'll have to email them and my instructor to ask if there is something that can be done about it.  I really appreciate all the responses, and I'm really glad that I found this site.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out, their tester was trying to send characters.  So I had to change the variables to chars, and use 
amountType = eventFile.next().charAt(0); to read the first character of the string.     I had to change some code in the Event class to deal with the primatives instead of strings.  All seems to be working now!